# Missing property (BadRequest) for Groovy template expansion

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

I'm using Resilience4j and I need to ignore some exceptions when using Retry. One of the exceptions is the: **org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest**

```
resilience4j.retry:
  instances:
    testA:
      maxAttempts: 5
      waitDuration: 100ms
      ignoreExceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest
        - java.net.ConnectException
        - java.lang.ArithmeticException
```

But I am not able to run the application because of the character **$**, the error occurs:

> Missing property (BadRequest) for Groovy template expansion. Defined
> keys [parent, inspectClassesForKotlinIC, projects ...

How can I use/escape this character inside application.yml file? The exception I need to ignore is the Bad Request, its full name contains the **$**. If I remove the **$** character the application runs normally, but I can't remove it because it's part of the exception's full name.

Comment: try escaping the symbol: `\$`

Comment: It's better to explain WHY your suggestion would work rather than just leaving a suggestion on it's own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used what @injecteer suggested and it worked:

> try escaping the symbol: $

Comment: As you just confirm the proposal from a comment, maybe it is better to move your "answer" to a comment on your question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the dollar sign can be escaped with a backslash.

The Spring Boot docs explain why the error happens in the first place, in the note below:

> You can automatically expand properties from the Gradle project by configuring the Java plugin’s processResources task to do so, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> tasks.named('processResources') {
>     expand(project.properties)
> }
> ```
>
> You can then refer to your Gradle project’s properties by using placeholders, as shown in the following example:
>
> app.name=${name}
> app.description=${description}
>
> Note: Gradle’s expand method uses Groovy’s SimpleTemplateEngine, which transforms ${..} tokens. The ${..} style conflicts with Spring’s own property placeholder mechanism. To use Spring property placeholders together with automatic expansion, escape the Spring property placeholders as follows: ${..}.

[Source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.properties-and-configuration.expand-properties)

This also applies to the dollar sign used in nested class names, as in OP's case: `WebClientResponseException$BadRequest`.